# Camel, Blueprint and camel:run

Tags: maven, apache-camel, apache-servicemix, aries

I'm starting pretty simple camel-blueprint project, it works fine (or something like fine) in karaf (servicemix), but in order to develop and debug on my machine i want to integrate it with camel-maven-plugin.

My blueprint looks like that:

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
       xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-blueprint.xsd">

    <cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="ru.igc.igsb" update-strategy="reload">
        <cm:default-properties>
            <cm:property name="csvPath" value="C:/files"/>
        </cm:default-properties>
    </cm:property-placeholder>

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <route>
            <from uri="file:{{csvPath}}"/>
            <log message="The message contains ${body}"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>

</blueprint>
```

my pom have this:

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <!-- optional, default value: org.apache.camel.spring.Main -->
    <configuration>
      <useBlueprint>true</useBlueprint>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

but **camel:run** fails:

```
EventDispatcher: Error during dispatch.
org.osgi.framework.ServiceException: Service factory exception: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.JdkProxyManager.createProxy(Lorg/osgi/framework/Bundle;Ljava/util/Collection;Ljava/util/concurrent/Callable;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl.getFactoryUnchecked(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:236)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl.getService(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:168)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.felix.framework.ServiceRegistry.getService(ServiceRegistry.java:308)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoSRBundleContext.getService(PojoSRBundleContext.java:156)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.namespace.NamespaceHandlerRegistryImpl.addingService(NamespaceHandlerRegistryImpl.java:90)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:896)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:261)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:233)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.serviceChanged(ServiceTracker.java:840)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeServiceListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:872)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:792)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireServiceEvent(EventDispatcher.java:540)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoSR$1.serviceChanged(PojoSR.java:66)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.felix.framework.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:116)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoSRBundleContext.registerService(PojoSRBundleContext.java:95)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.registerService(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:404)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ServiceRecipe.register(ServiceRecipe.java:184)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.registerServices(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:662)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.doRun(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:330)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.JdkProxyManager.createProxy(Lorg/osgi/framework/Bundle;Ljava/util/Collection;Ljava/util/concurrent/Callable;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ReferenceRecipe.internalCreate(ReferenceRecipe.java:98)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:64)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperty(BeanRecipe.java:799)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperties(BeanRecipe.java:773)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperties(BeanRecipe.java:754)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:720)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:64)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstances(BlueprintRepository.java:219)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstance(BlueprintRepository.java:198)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.create(BlueprintRepository.java:137)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ServiceRecipe.createRecipe(ServiceRecipe.java:370)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ServiceRecipe.createService(ServiceRecipe.java:278)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ServiceRecipe.internalGetService(ServiceRecipe.java:248)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ServiceRecipe.getService(ServiceRecipe.java:327)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ServiceRecipe$TriggerServiceFactory.getService(ServiceRecipe.java:430)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl.getFactoryUnchecked(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:232)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.JdkProxyManager.createProxy(Lorg/osgi/framework/Bundle;Ljava/util/Collection;Ljava/util/concurrent/Callable;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.AbstractServiceReferenceRecipe.createProxy(AbstractServiceReferenceRecipe.java:236)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ReferenceRecipe.internalCreate(ReferenceRecipe.java:82)
    ... 42 more
[ERROR] *************************************
[ERROR] Error occurred while running main from: org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.Main
[ERROR]
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably there's a missing dependency (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-9321).

**Solution**

Add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.aries.blueprint</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.aries.blueprint.core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

into the *dependencies*-Section of your pom.xml (root directory, not the derived *pom.xml* under */bin*).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have just used the camel sample from ServiceMix 5.4.x (https://github.com/apache/servicemix/tree/servicemix-5.4.x/examples/camel/camel-blueprint), replaced the existing blueprint with yours and added the plugin to pom file

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.1</version>
    <!-- optional, default value: org.apache.camel.spring.Main -->
    <configuration>
      <useBlueprint>true</useBlueprint>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

It worked for me. Please compare your project (especially the pom file) with the sample project. Be sure you use the same camel and camel plugin version.